# Docker compose with networks and "internal" property example

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I tried to find example of usage "[internal](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#internal)" property with a network declaration in docker-compose.yml v2.

Other words I search how to do this:

```
docker network create someName --internal
```

but in docker-compose.yml.

I get error when try to use this variant:

```
version: '2'

services:
# services definition

networks:
  someName:
    internal: true
```

Error message:

```
The Compose file '.\docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
networks.someName value Additional properties are not allowed ('internal' was unexpected)
```

Comment: you sure you are using correct compose version? also doesn't your network has to be overlay (`driver: overlay`) for the internal to make sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upgrade to docker-compose 1.9 or later, internal networks are a new feature of the docker-compose.yml.

Instructions to upgrade are on [the compose releases page](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases).

Comment: Yes, you right. I'm using docker for windows, and I thought that docker-compose automatically updates to latest version when I update docker engine, but I was wrong, Docker for windows installs docker engine, docker-compose and docker-machine, but updates come separately. So, I downloaded docker-compose-Windows-x86_64.exe and replaced docker-compose.exe in `C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin`. All works well now, thanks!